# Matlab -nodesktop and ANSI colors on warning and errors

Tags: matlab, ansi-colors

I have the habit to use matlab with the `-nodesktop` option, and I was wondering if it is possible to print warnings and errors in colors.
` 
For the moment, I tried a few things

- I tried to change the matlab function in `warning.m`, but those functions are built-in and I can't modify them
- I tried to follow [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103129-how-do-i-overload-built-in-matlab-functions) and I had to create a folder `@char` somewhere in my path with a function in there with something like this

  `function varargout = warning(varargin)
      fprintf('\033[33m'):
      [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('warning',varargin{:});
      fprintf('\033[0m');
   end`

  I tried not to use directly the `warning` function because I would have an infinite loop. The problem is that some warnings (for example in the `imshow` function) are called like this

  `warning(message('images:imshow:magnificationMustBeFitForDockedFigure'))`

  and it doesn't call the function in the `@char` folder.
- I also thought of creating another program that would call matlab and color it when it founds warnings or errors (or to call matlab with an intelligent shell command coloring the lines where `warning` appears but it seems difficult).

Does anyone have an idea of how I could solve my problem ?

Comment: If you start Matlab normally and remove all auxiliary panels and toolbars, it will look like `-nodesktop` but with the fancy text colouring

Comment: Well yes, but I'm kind of used to terminator and I'd like to keep it for matlab. Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to also override the warning function for the @message class. See what happens when you run:

```
metaclass(message('images:imshow:magnificationMustBeFitForDockedFigure'))
```